# Change button text on ASPxPopupControl buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, devexpress

I am trying to change the text of ASPxPopupControl buttons (I have not written the ASPxPopupControl code myself. Those guys are long gone. :) So it's up to me). As far as I know, the ASPxPopupControl default buttons are used and if I want to change the button text I have to add code to the .aspx file. I have tried searching for an answer on the DevExpress docs and the world wide web. But could not find anything that matches my needs. I am very grateful for any ideas.

This is the buttons I am talking about:
[image]

The ASPxPopupControl code (There is an attempt to add a custom button but it does not work.):

```
<dxpc:ASPxPopupControl ID="someLongID" runat="server" 
                AllowDragging="True" ClientInstanceName="someLongID" 
                CloseAction="CloseButton" HeaderText="Varning!" Modal="True" 
                PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" 
                Width="300px">
    <ContentCollection>
        <dxpc:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl3" 
                        runat="server" Enabled="True">
            <p>
            <br />
            </p>
            <p align="right">
                <input 
                id="Button1" 
                onclick="javascript:someLongID.Hide();" 
                type="button" value="Stäng" />
            </p>
        </dxpc:PopupControlContentControl>
    </ContentCollection>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFB6C1" />
</dxpc:ASPxPopupControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't implement you own popup edit form, but use the [built-in](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/PopupEditForm.aspx) one, it is necessary to access the required text setting via the [ASPxGridView.SettingsText](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewTextSettings.members) (CommandUpdate, etc.).

Comment: That did it! It work great! Figured out that I can solve it like this:  `grdKammarstatus.SettingsCommandButton.UpdateButton.Text = "Uppdatera` or `<CancelButton Text="Avbryt" />
                        <UpdateButton Text="Uppdatera" />` within a `<SettingsCommandButton>`  Thanks again!

Comment: Great! You can accept my answer to close this ticket then.

Comment: Was just about too

Answer (score -1):

I think you can change the text content in the item property (in "Properties") which is located in the right down corner on VS. 
you can click on the item in "Design" mode and then check its setting in "Properties"
Hope this helps

Comment: I can find the properties panel you are refering to, but nothing that Changes the CloseButton and UpdateButton text inside the popup. I can find  CloseButton css properties but nothing that says CloseButton.value or text.